# How to implement a JointPositionController

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to implement a JointPositionController so I can conveniently tune PID-values with rqt_gui (Tell me if there is a better method). I have a working JointTrajectoryController which I tried changing to be a position controller. I want to change it because I don't know what values to publish to just move the joints, while with the JointPositionController I can simply publish a float and the robot should move to the position.

My `ros_controllers.yaml` looks like this:

```
irb4600_40_255_arm_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
  joints:
    - joint_1
    - joint_2
    - joint_3
    - joint_4
    - joint_5
    - joint_6
  gains:    # manually tuned
     joint_1: { p: 2000.0, d: 500.0, i: 50.0, i_clamp: 10000 }
     joint_2: { p: 100000.0, d: 100000.0, i: 2000, i_clamp: 10000 }
     joint_3: { p: 10000.0, d: 800.0, i: 500.0, i_clamp: 1000 }
     joint_4: { p: 18000, d: 200, i: 0.01, i_clamp: 10000 }
     joint_5: { p: 100, d: 0, i: 0, i_clamp: 0}
     joint_6: { p: 8, d: 0, i: 0, i_clamp: 0}
```

I exchanged the `effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController` of my working controller with `effort_controllers/JointPositionController`.

In my `ros_controllers.launch` file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
  <rosparam file="$(find irb4600_40_255_moveit_config)/config/ros_controllers.yaml" command="load"/>

  <!-- Load the controllers -->
  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
    output="screen" args="irb4600_40_255_arm_controller "/>    
</launch>
```

This launch file get's called in my launch file starting gazebo like this:

```
<!-- Load joint controller parameters for Gazebo -->
  <rosparam file="$(find irb4600_40_255_moveit_config)/config/gazebo_controllers.yaml" />
  <!-- Spawn Gazebo ROS controllers -->
  <node name="gazebo_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen" args="joint_state_controller" />
  <!-- Load ROS controllers -->
  <include file="$(dirname)/ros_controllers.launch"/>
```

Now when I try `roslaunch irb4600_40_255_moveit_config sim.launch`, which launches my gazebo launch file as well, i get:

```
[ERROR] [1648127146.564436320, 0.012000000]: No joint given (namespace: /irb4600_40_255_arm_controller)
[ERROR] [1648127146.564570962, 0.013000000]: Failed to initialize the controller
[ERROR] [1648127146.564650287, 0.013000000]: Initializing controller 'irb4600_40_255_arm_controller' failed
```

This does not happen for EXACT SAME code, with the controller type switched from `JointPositionController` to `JointTrajectoryController`.

I aswell tried implementing it after the example of the [rrbot](https://github.com/lyleokoth/rrbot).

The `ros_controllers.launch`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
  <rosparam file="$(find irb4600_40_255_moveit_config)/config/ros_controllers.yaml" command="load"/>

  <!-- Load the controllers -->    
  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
    output="screen" ns="/abb_irb4600_40_255" 
    args="joint_states_controller
          joint1_position_controller 
          joint2_position_controller
          joint3_position_controller
          joint4_position_controller
          joint5_position_controller
          joint6_position_controller "/>

</launch>
```

The `ros_controllers.yaml`:

```
irb4600_40_255_arm_controller:

  # Publish all joint states -----------------------------------
  joint_states_controller:
      type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
      publish_rate: 25

  # Position Controllers ---------------------------------------
  joint1_position_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: joint_1
      pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
        
  joint2_position_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: joint_2
      pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0} 

  joint3_position_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: joint_3
      pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0} 

  joint4_position_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: joint_4
      pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0} 

  joint5_position_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: joint_5
      pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0} 

  joint6_position_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: joint_6
      pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
```

The error in this case is:
`[WARN] [1648127958.676596, 20.498000]: Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.`

I am using ROS Noetic/Gazebo 11.9.0/rviz 1.14.14, my system is Ubuntu 20.04.

I hope it is not too confusing to read. Pls send help.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397942/how-to-implement-a-jointpositioncontroller/) by [joff](https://answers.ros.org/users/99933/joff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2022-03-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

with the help of a friend I was able to figure out the problems.

I ended up creating an extra file for the controller: `joint_state_controller.yaml`

```
  # Publish all joint states -----------------------------------
  joint_state_controller:
      type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
      publish_rate: 25

  # Position Controllers ---------------------------------------
  joint1_position_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: joint_1
      pid: { p: 8000.0, d: 1000.0, i: 100.0, i_clamp: 0 } 

  joint2_position_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: joint_2
      pid: { p: 100000.0, d: 100000.0, i: 2000, i_clamp: 0 }

  joint3_position_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: joint_3
      pid: { p: 10000.0, d: 800.0, i: 500.0, i_clamp: 0 }

  joint4_position_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: joint_4
      pid: { p: 18000, d: 200, i: 0.01, i_clamp: 0 }

  joint5_position_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: joint_5
      pid: { p: 100, d: 0, i: 0, i_clamp: 0}

  joint6_position_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: joint_6
      pid: { p: 8, d: 0, i: 0, i_clamp: 0}
```

I think the main difference here is that I don't have `irb4600_40_255_arm_controller` as a namespace in the first line of the file.

Now I call this file in my `ros_controllers.launch` as this:

```
  <rosparam file="$(find irb4600_40_255_moveit_config)/config/joint_state_controller.yaml" command="load"/>
  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
    output="screen"
    args="joint_state_controller
          joint1_position_controller 
          joint2_position_controller
          joint3_position_controller
          joint4_position_controller
          joint5_position_controller
          joint6_position_controller "/>
```

I think it was somehow a problem with the namespace, so I ended up using none.

Some further tips which helped me:

- Look in `rostopics list` if you controllers are publishing, to make sure they get loaded
- Don't set you PID values too low in
  the new controller, as I had simply p
  = 100 which was not ennough to move the robot even a little bit.

---

Originally posted by [joff](https://answers.ros.org/users/99933/joff/) with karma: 40 on 2022-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1